# How to bypass fromUriString in spring restTemplate call

Tags: spring, resttemplate

In Spring, the `restTemplate` call goes down to `fromUriString` and uses a regex on the URI. I need to pass in a password with a hash character `#` and the regex is dropping the `#`.

How can I tell it to ignore the `#`, and pass the URL as is?

Comment: Could you please add a small code example?

Comment: Sure thing and thanks for looking.

I am using the exchange method:

ResponseEntity<AuthTokenInfo> response = restTemplate.exchange(buildUrl(userName, password, url),HttpMethod.POST, request, AuthTokenInfo.class);

The url would be for example:
https://www.somecompany.com/rest/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=someclientid&client_secret=something&username=user@useremail.com&password=blah#111

Comment: And what is buildUrl(...) doing? I think I (or someone else) can only help you with a code example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Hopefully this is a little clearer:

`ResponseEntity<AuthTokenInfo> response = restTemplate.exchange(buildUrl(userName, password, url),HttpMethod.POST, request, AuthTokenInfo.class);`

The buildUrl would return for example:
https://www.somecompany.com/rest/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=someclientid&client_secret=something&username=user@useremail.com&password=blah#111

Comment: I ended up using the Apache HttpClient to get the call to work with no issues.  Seems like Spring forces a filter on URL's when using RestTemplate.